# Struts2 - Validation Problem

Tags: java, validation, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have started a web application using struts 2. Apache tomcat 6.0 is my web server. It is clear to me that we can validate data using action.validation.xml.but each time i will pressed the submit button repeating the error message.Help me for Solving this problem.

Comment: Do you mean that even if you enter correct data you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Without your code and the error message you are getting no one will be able to help you. So please post your code and error messages.

Any way if you have here is a nice tutorial on [Struts2 validation using XML file](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-validation-using-xml-example-1.html). Hope this will help.